# Displaying integers with lagrange four square theorem in mathematica or matlab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, number-theory

As I am new on MatLab and Mathematica, I am trying to solve two (easy) problems using one of these two programmes.

"In number theory, Lagrange’s four-square theorem, states that every natural number n can be written as n= a^2+ b^2 + c^2 + d^2, where a, b, c, d are integers.

1. Given a natural number n, display all possible integers a, b, c, d.
2. The number of ways to write a natural number
   n as the sum of four squares is denoted by r4(n). Using Jacobi's theorem, plot the function r4(n)
   and compare it with the function 8n√(log n)."

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  Did you mean to post this on your blog ?

Comment: The questions are: how do I find and display all possible integers for a, b, c, d using Lagrange's theorem and how do I plot the function r4(n) from Jacobi's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer using Mathematica build-in functions

`PowerRepresentations[n,k,p]` gives the distinct representation of the integer n as sum of k non-negative p th integer powers.

Attention: by distinct we mean: if n = n1^p + n2^p + n3^p ... the function returns k-tuples such that n1<=n2<=n3...

Example:

```
PowerRepresentation[20,4,2]
```

gives

```
{{0,0,2,4},{1,1,3,3}}
```

To get the number of possible representations of integer n as a sum  of d squares you can use the `SquaresR[d,n]` function (your rd(n) functions).

Example:

```
SquaresR[4,20]
```

prints

```
144
```

However as you explained there is still some works because rd(n) also returns negative solutions and permuted ones.

For instance:

```
SquaresR[2,20]
```

returns

```
8
```

You must understand 8 as counting without distinction:

- 4 sign changes:

  {2,4},{2,-4},{-2,4},{-2,-4}

times

- 2 permutations

  {2,4},{4,2}